# configure freezes at "checking for ld used by GCC" - MSYS2

Tags: bash, gcc, configure, msys2

I have recently been experiencing problems with the configure step of two open source projects, GNU GetText and W3M.

The configure step fails at the same place for both projects.

**checking for ld used by GCC...**

**System details:**

- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- MSYS2
- gcc --version: gcc.exe (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project) 5.2.0
- gcc -dumpmachine: x86_64-w64-mingw32
- bash --version: GNU bash, version 4.3.42(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

The following is the code that configure uses to perform this test.

```
  # Check if gcc -print-prog-name=ld gives a path.
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for ld used by GCC" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for ld used by GCC... " >&6; }
  case $host in
  *-*-mingw*)
    # gcc leaves a trailing carriage return which upsets mingw
    ac_prog=`($CC -print-prog-name=ld) 2>&5 | tr -d '\015'` ;;
  *)
    ac_prog=`($CC -print-prog-name=ld) 2>&5` ;;
  esac
  case $ac_prog in
    # Accept absolute paths.
    [\\/]* | [A-Za-z]:[\\/]*)
      re_direlt='/[^/][^/]*/\.\./'
      # Canonicalize the path of ld
      ac_prog=`echo $ac_prog| sed 's%\\\\%/%g'`
      while echo $ac_prog | grep "$re_direlt" > /dev/null 2>&1; do
        ac_prog=`echo $ac_prog| sed "s%$re_direlt%/%"`
      done
      test -z "$LD" && LD="$ac_prog"
      ;;
  "")
    # If it fails, then pretend we aren't using GCC.
    ac_prog=ld
    ;;
  *)
    # If it is relative, then search for the first ld in PATH.
    with_gnu_ld=unknown
    ;;
  esac
```

I added debugging code to determine exactly where the problem is occurring. It is happening in the while loop in which grep is called.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why, but I found that the following packages interfered with configure.

- mingw-w64-i686-grep
- mingw-w64-i686-sed
- mingw-w64-x86_64-grep
- mingw-w64-x86_64-sed

These packages appear to be obsolete. When I removed them configure worked.

Comment: I have the same problem with msys2. but these packages does not exist for me.

Comment: Run the build in the MSYS2 shell, not the MINGW32 or MINGW64 shell.